# Nativescript building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64

Tags: xcode, nativescript, ios-simulator

We recently updated our project **my-ns-project** from NS 6 to 7. Our project depends on a custom plugin **our-custom-plugin** (upgraded from NS 6 to 7 also) that is written by ourselves. Within this custom plugin we depend on these 2 pods. When we build our project my-ns-project that launches an iOS emulator, we get the error message in the title. However if we launch the .xcworkspace file and build within xcode, it builds fine on the iOS emulator. Can anyone share some good ideas to resolving this issue? Thank you!

> our-custom-plugin, /src/platforms/ios/Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 4.1.0'

# If comment out the following line, we don't get the error message anymore
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', '~> 3.4.2'
```

**Build Env**

NS CLI: 7.0.11

Xcode: 12.2

iOS Emulator: iPhone 12, 14.2

```
Saving metadata generation's stderr stream to: /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/metadata-generation-stderr-i386.txt
~/my-ns-project/platforms/ios
ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TKLiveSync.framework/TKLiveSync, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NativeScript.framework/NativeScript, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BEMCheckBox/BEMCheckBox.framework/BEMCheckBox, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseABTesting/FirebaseABTesting.framework/FirebaseABTesting, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCrashlytics/FirebaseCrashlytics.framework/FirebaseCrashlytics, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstallations/FirebaseInstallations.framework/FirebaseInstallations, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseRemoteConfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.framework/FirebaseRemoteConfig, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport.framework/GoogleDataTransport, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/IQKeyboardManager/IQKeyboardManager.framework/IQKeyboardManager, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MDFInternationalization/MDFInternationalization.framework/MDFInternationalization, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MaterialComponents/MaterialComponents.framework/MaterialComponents, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf/Protobuf.framework/Protobuf, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/my-ns-project/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb/nanopb.framework/nanopb, building for iOS Simulator-i386 but attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_pb_ostream_from_buffer", referenced from:
      _nano_two_pass_encoding in GoogleAppMeasurement(encoder_common_1fe7b585e260c4375f60bb018d8aad7b.o)
  "_pb_encode_string", referenced from:
      _nano_encode_string in GoogleAppMeasurement(encoder_common_1fe7b585e260c4375f60bb018d8aad7b.o)
  "_pb_encode_varint", referenced from:
      _nano_encode_repeated_uint64 in GoogleAppMeasurement(encoder_common_1fe7b585e260c4375f60bb018d8aad7b.o)
  "_pb_decode_varint", referenced from:
      _nano_decode_repeated_uint64 in GoogleAppMeasurement(decoder_common_2cdf50773e3bd04e04659445703c8a13.o)
  "_pb_encode_submessage", referenced from:
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_encoder_443423dd0ea6ea4589a3eed80d3741b1.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_encoder_61f7ce63f55f0ec7a3bd2a0fe2ad8afc.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_client_property_encoder_f8b765117cea856cdea5e2fccea50e83.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_custom_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_custom_property_encoder_ee91a3e80ab28732d3416aa15492b7d9.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp_encoder_0a05d8b969c3edafbb942fe5df513e5e.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_event in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_event_encoder_34455cc132b4a1860cdef61bcb926939.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_event_config in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_event_config_encoder_cbdb16bb13403f14bc11a93f6b8098da.o)
      ...
  "_pb_read", referenced from:
      _apmpb_decode_repeated_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_decoder_be175130f5eb18e1a1fd22dff70fde92.o)
      _apmpb_decode_repeated_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_decoder_14a20321b55f247ef384c2ddbeb04242.o)
      _apmpb_decode_repeated_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_client_property_decoder_f181e6dcd2a62b2be52c3f45375e31ea.o)
      _apmpb_decode_repeated_custom_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_custom_property_decoder_6f0666060734ce317b0c577c066a28db.o)
      _apmpb_decode_repeated_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp_decoder_b6aeb6cd0692484c7597c9a307ada616.o)
      _apmpb_decode_repeated_event in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_event_decoder_3988eb9f2f518ccb2a2595ebc8a6c2af.o)
      _apmpb_decode_repeated_event_config in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_event_config_decoder_7a459e34208e3ab42ac3301f42d8a3e7.o)
      ...
  "_pb_decode", referenced from:
      _apmpb_decode_app_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_app_property_decoder_ce6857b1f5c49463a1fa6d75bd34bc19.o)
      _apmpb_decode_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_decoder_be175130f5eb18e1a1fd22dff70fde92.o)
      _apmpb_decode_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_decoder_14a20321b55f247ef384c2ddbeb04242.o)
      _apmpb_decode_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_client_property_decoder_f181e6dcd2a62b2be52c3f45375e31ea.o)
      _apmpb_decode_custom_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_custom_property_decoder_6f0666060734ce317b0c577c066a28db.o)
      _apmpb_decode_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp_decoder_b6aeb6cd0692484c7597c9a307ada616.o)
      _apmpb_decode_event in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_event_decoder_3988eb9f2f518ccb2a2595ebc8a6c2af.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBStringInt64Dictionary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRProtoUtils.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBEnumArray", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRProtoUtils.o)
  "_GULLogInfo", referenced from:
      ___44+[UIViewController(APMScreenClassName) load]_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement(UIViewController+APMScreenClassName_f1b7bb9312d73b76eeaa1d3ce4550c4a.o)
  "_GULIsLoggableLevel", referenced from:
      -[APMMonitor isLoggableLevel:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMonitor_2e7ec8093ee95400a0175bdb2180a3bc.o)
  "_GULSetLoggerLevel", referenced from:
      -[APMMonitor setDebugModeEnabled:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMonitor_2e7ec8093ee95400a0175bdb2180a3bc.o)
      -[APMMonitor setVerboseLoggingEnabled:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMonitor_2e7ec8093ee95400a0175bdb2180a3bc.o)
  "_GULLogBasic", referenced from:
      -[APMASLLogger logMessage:logTag:messageCode:withLogLevel:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMASLLogger_31b5e756aa4060d42f3eaa7097a057ea.o)
  "_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusOK", referenced from:
      -[APMMeasurement networkUploadCompletionHandlerWithResponse:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_bb2d23c2eed19b2d092e1d9b92482203.o)
      -[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_bb2d23c2eed19b2d092e1d9b92482203.o)
      -[APMETaskManager handleFetchingExperimentsResponse:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMETaskManager_8c4ebd34f929702aa14a32fe8a297a39.o)
      ___46-[APMMeasurement(URL) requestDeferredDeepLink]_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement+URL_4777024219eac4de2cebc8ab7876e65c.o)
  "_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeNotFound", referenced from:
      -[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_bb2d23c2eed19b2d092e1d9b92482203.o)
  "_GULLogWarning", referenced from:
      +[APMMeasurement sharedInstance] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_bb2d23c2eed19b2d092e1d9b92482203.o)
      -[APMUserDefaults objectForKey:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMUserDefaults_ffd6a8d7a056da12b38495dcdb49beb9.o)
      -[APMUserDefaults setObject:forKey:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMUserDefaults_ffd6a8d7a056da12b38495dcdb49beb9.o)
      -[APMUserDefaults synchronize] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMUserDefaults_ffd6a8d7a056da12b38495dcdb49beb9.o)
      ___44+[UIViewController(APMScreenClassName) load]_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement(UIViewController+APMScreenClassName_f1b7bb9312d73b76eeaa1d3ce4550c4a.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBEnumDescriptor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppDelegateSwizzler", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMAnalytics_1c32bf47ceea74a2420a74a5a6ebdc08.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppEnvironmentUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRUIViewControllerInstrument.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMEExperimentRequestBuilder_dc697084a62a8d3ab2f2ca89be2c962b.o)
  "_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeNotModified", referenced from:
      -[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_bb2d23c2eed19b2d092e1d9b92482203.o)
      ___46-[APMMeasurement(URL) requestDeferredDeepLink]_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement+URL_4777024219eac4de2cebc8ab7876e65c.o)
  "_GULLogError", referenced from:
      +[APMAnalytics startWithAppID:origin:options:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMAnalytics_1c32bf47ceea74a2420a74a5a6ebdc08.o)
      -[APMUserDefaults synchronize] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMUserDefaults_ffd6a8d7a056da12b38495dcdb49beb9.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Config", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULSwizzler", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRProxyObjectHelper.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRSelectorInstrumentor.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(UIViewController+APMScreenClassName_f1b7bb9312d73b76eeaa1d3ce4550c4a.o)
  "_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusNoContent", referenced from:
      -[APMMeasurement networkUploadCompletionHandlerWithResponse:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_bb2d23c2eed19b2d092e1d9b92482203.o)
      -[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_bb2d23c2eed19b2d092e1d9b92482203.o)
      -[APMETaskManager handleFetchingExperimentsResponse:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMETaskManager_8c4ebd34f929702aa14a32fe8a297a39.o)
      ___46-[APMMeasurement(URL) requestDeferredDeepLink]_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement+URL_4777024219eac4de2cebc8ab7876e65c.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
  "_FIRLogNotice", referenced from:
      -[FPRNetworkTrace didUploadFileWithURL:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRNetworkTrace.o)
      -[FPRNetworkTrace didReceiveFileURL:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRNetworkTrace.o)
      ___FPRAssert in FirebasePerformance(FPRDiagnostics.o)
      ___27+[FPRDiagnostics isEnabled]_block_invoke in FirebasePerformance(FPRDiagnostics.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULObjectSwizzler", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRNetworkTrace.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRObjectInstrumentor.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRNSURLConnectionInstrument.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDTCORTransport", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRGDTCCLogger.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRComponent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FIRAnalyticsConnector(FIRAnalyticsConnector_abbf040ca2e41b3e7e127706182b4c49.o)
  "_FIRLogWarning", referenced from:
      -[FPRClient logTrace:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      _FPRTruncatedURLString in FirebasePerformance(FPRDataUtils.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogLevelFilter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FPRGTMLogLevelFilter in FirebasePerformance(FPRGTMLogLevelFilter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULNetwork", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMAnalytics_1c32bf47ceea74a2420a74a5a6ebdc08.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_bb2d23c2eed19b2d092e1d9b92482203.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMAppDelegateInterceptor_90ee75e2ed1066c8180815f58bc19554.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMETaskManager_8c4ebd34f929702aa14a32fe8a297a39.o)
  "_FIRLogError", referenced from:
      -[FIRHTTPMetric initWithURL:HTTPMethod:] in FirebasePerformance(FIRHTTPMetric.o)
      -[FIRHTTPMetric stop] in FirebasePerformance(FIRHTTPMetric.o)
      ___17+[FPRClient load]_block_invoke in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      -[FPRClient logTrace:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      -[FPRClient logNetworkTrace:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      -[FPRClient logGaugeMetric:forSessionId:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      -[FPRClient processAndLogEvent:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogLevelFilter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FPRGTMLogLevelFilter in FirebasePerformance(FPRGTMLogLevelFilter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FIRAnalyticsConnector(FIRAnalyticsConnector_abbf040ca2e41b3e7e127706182b4c49.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ecfd685f77bebed29512ce31159d5667.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRConfigurations.o)
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRRemoteConfigFlags.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBFileDescriptor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPBRootObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FPRMSGPerfMetricRoot in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
  "_pb_encode", referenced from:
      _nano_two_pass_encoding in GoogleAppMeasurement(encoder_common_1fe7b585e260c4375f60bb018d8aad7b.o)
  "_kFIRAppReadyToConfigureSDKNotification", referenced from:
      +[FPRClient load] in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBDescriptor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
  "_kFIRAppNameKey", referenced from:
      ___17+[FPRClient load]_block_invoke in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRRemoteConfig", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebasePerformance(FPRRemoteConfigFlags.o)
  "_kFIRLoggerAnalytics", referenced from:
      +[FIRAnalytics startWithConfiguration:options:] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_ecfd685f77bebed29512ce31159d5667.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPBMessage", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FPRMSGPerfMetric in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FPRMSGTraceMetric in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FPRMSGNetworkRequestMetric in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FPRMSGPerfSession in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FPRMSGGaugeMetric in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FPRMSGCpuMetricReading in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FPRMSGIosMemoryReading in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
      ...
  "_FIRLogDebug", referenced from:
      ___22-[FPRClient logTrace:]_block_invoke in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      ___29-[FPRClient logNetworkTrace:]_block_invoke in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      +[FPRClient cleanupClearcutCacheDirectory] in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      ___46-[FPRGaugeManager prepareAndDispatchGaugeData]_block_invoke in FirebasePerformance(FPRGaugeManager.o)
      -[FPRMemoryGaugeCollector captureMemoryGaugeAtFrequency:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRMemoryGaugeCollector.o)
      ___41-[FPRNetworkTrace setValue:forAttribute:]_block_invoke in FirebasePerformance(FPRNetworkTrace.o)
      -[FPRCPUGaugeCollector captureCPUGaugeAtFrequency:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRCPUGaugeCollector.o)
      ...
  "_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeCannotAcceptTraffic", referenced from:
      -[APMMeasurement networkUploadCompletionHandlerWithResponse:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_bb2d23c2eed19b2d092e1d9b92482203.o)
      -[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_bb2d23c2eed19b2d092e1d9b92482203.o)
      -[APMETaskManager handleFetchingExperimentsResponse:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMETaskManager_8c4ebd34f929702aa14a32fe8a297a39.o)
  "_pb_istream_from_buffer", referenced from:
      _apmpb_decode_app_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_app_property_decoder_ce6857b1f5c49463a1fa6d75bd34bc19.o)
      _apmpb_decode_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_decoder_be175130f5eb18e1a1fd22dff70fde92.o)
      _apmpb_decode_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_decoder_14a20321b55f247ef384c2ddbeb04242.o)
      _apmpb_decode_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_client_property_decoder_f181e6dcd2a62b2be52c3f45375e31ea.o)
      _apmpb_decode_custom_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_custom_property_decoder_6f0666060734ce317b0c577c066a28db.o)
      _apmpb_decode_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp_decoder_b6aeb6cd0692484c7597c9a307ada616.o)
      _apmpb_decode_event in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_event_decoder_3988eb9f2f518ccb2a2595ebc8a6c2af.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBRootObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FPRMSGPerfMetricRoot in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
  "_FIRLogInfo", referenced from:
      -[FIRHTTPMetric initWithURL:HTTPMethod:] in FirebasePerformance(FIRHTTPMetric.o)
      -[FPRClient processAndLogEvent:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      ___InstrumentURLSessionTaskDidCompleteWithError_block_invoke in FirebasePerformance(FPRNSURLSessionDelegateInstrument.o)
      ___InstrumentURLSessionTaskDidSendBodyDataTotalBytesSentTotalBytesExpectedToSend_block_invoke in FirebasePerformance(FPRNSURLSessionDelegateInstrument.o)
      -[FPRNetworkTrace initWithURLRequest:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRNetworkTrace.o)
      -[FPRNSURLSessionDelegate URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRNSURLSessionDelegate.o)
      -[FPRNSURLSessionDelegate URLSession:task:didSendBodyData:totalBytesSent:totalBytesExpectedToSend:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRNSURLSessionDelegate.o)
      ...
  "_kFIRLoggerPerf", referenced from:
      -[FIRHTTPMetric initWithURL:HTTPMethod:] in FirebasePerformance(FIRHTTPMetric.o)
      -[FIRHTTPMetric stop] in FirebasePerformance(FIRHTTPMetric.o)
      ___17+[FPRClient load]_block_invoke in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      -[FPRClient logTrace:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      ___22-[FPRClient logTrace:]_block_invoke in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      -[FPRClient logNetworkTrace:] in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      ___29-[FPRClient logNetworkTrace:]_block_invoke in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBMessage", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FPRMSGPerfMetric in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FPRMSGTraceMetric in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FPRMSGNetworkRequestMetric in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FPRMSGPerfSession in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FPRMSGGaugeMetric in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FPRMSGCpuMetricReading in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FPRMSGIosMemoryReading in FirebasePerformance(PerfMetric.pbobjc.o)
      ...
  "_TNSInitializeLiveSync", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_kFIRAppIsDefaultAppKey", referenced from:
      ___17+[FPRClient load]_block_invoke in FirebasePerformance(FPRClient.o)
  "_pb_encode_tag_for_field", referenced from:
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_encoder_443423dd0ea6ea4589a3eed80d3741b1.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_encoder_61f7ce63f55f0ec7a3bd2a0fe2ad8afc.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_client_property_encoder_f8b765117cea856cdea5e2fccea50e83.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_custom_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_custom_property_encoder_ee91a3e80ab28732d3416aa15492b7d9.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp_encoder_0a05d8b969c3edafbb942fe5df513e5e.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_event in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_event_encoder_34455cc132b4a1860cdef61bcb926939.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_event_config in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_event_config_encoder_cbdb16bb13403f14bc11a93f6b8098da.o)
      ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled into this while having the same issue but i happened to solve it. My issue was on another google pod. Maybe they did something to them recently.

Anyway, try this, it worked for me:

Specify IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0 in <App_Resources>/iOS/build.xcconfig , this way Xcode will build it only as 64bit and run on the simulator. The con is that it wont work on less than ios 11.